# Function/Method for Altair to read json file

Tags: python, altair

In python potly there is a function to read JSON file i.e., .to_potly_json() by using this function we can understand every aspect of the charts. Is there a function for "Altair" to do the same?

I have tried that function in potly but I'm trying to do the same in Altair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see you plots both as a dictionary (`chart.to_dict()`) and json (`print(chart.to_json())`). Here is an example:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
).to_dict()
```

```
{'config': {'view': {'continuousWidth': 400, 'continuousHeight': 300}},
 'data': {'name': 'data-c2a3e89ba9d5d1687d5e8c28d630a033'},
 'mark': 'bar',
 'encoding': {'x': {'field': 'a', 'type': 'nominal'},
  'y': {'field': 'b', 'type': 'quantitative'}},
 '$schema': 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.2.0.json',
 'datasets': {'data-c2a3e89ba9d5d1687d5e8c28d630a033': [{'a': 'A', 'b': 28},
   {'a': 'B', 'b': 55},
   {'a': 'C', 'b': 43},
   {'a': 'D', 'b': 91},
   {'a': 'E', 'b': 81},
   {'a': 'F', 'b': 53},
   {'a': 'G', 'b': 19},
   {'a': 'H', 'b': 87},
   {'a': 'I', 'b': 52}]}}
```